# use of method startswith() and re.findall() in python to extract exact words

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a text file like below,

```
&attri 'abc' real
&attri 'cde' real
&attri 'efg' {'0', '1'}
&attri 'ghi_jkl' real
&attri 'lmn' real
&attri 'nop' real
&attri 'pqr_stu_uvw' real
&attri 'xy_z' {'0', '1'}
```

I want to extract all the words `'abc', 'cde', 'efg', 'ghi_jkl', 'lmn', 'nop', 'pqr_stu_uvw', 'xy_z'` from that file.

I wrote the following code, but it prints just `[]`.

```
import re

col = []

with open('text1.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        l = line.strip()
        if l.startswith('&attri'):
            col.append(re.findall(r"'(.{1})'", l))
print(col)
```

Thank you for helping me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex here considering that you always need to extract second word of each line out of file. Use `split()` and extract second split:

```
col = []

with open('text1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().startswith('&attri'):
            col.append(line.split()[1].strip("'"))

print(col)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace 2 lines with

```
       if l.startswith('&attri'):
            col.append(l.split()[1].strip("'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

s = '''&attri 'abc' real
&attri 'cde' real
&attri 'efg' {'0', '1'}
&attri 'ghi_jkl' real
&attri 'lmn' real
&attri 'nop' real
&attri 'pqr_stu_uvw' real
&attri 'xy_z' {'0', '1'}'''


print(re.findall("'[a-zA-Z_]*'",s)
```

## Result:

```
["'abc'", "'cde'", "'efg'", "'ghi_jkl'", "'lmn'", "'nop'", "'pqr_stu_uvw'", "'xy_z'"]
```